# How can I get Goaccess running under Nginx?

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-18.04, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, goaccess

I need to configure Nginx to make Goaccess work.

My environment is:

- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- Nginx 1.17.1  [ self-configure , path=/root ]
- Lets Encrypt
- sshfs
- goaccess  [ --enable-utf8 --enable-geoip=legacy --with-openssl ]

*Since this is a self-answered Q/A I'm not including my failed attempts, but instead posting my solution. Feel free to edit it or post another answer improving the current code*.

Comment: Hi Crotel, I have edit your post to conform with the Q/A format that Stack Overflow has, the answer currently is a community wiki, if you like to post it under your own account, post it as an answer then ping me (comment under community wiki, so I can delete the current answer), or flag for moderator (custom reason), explain that you like to post under your own name and the community wiki needs to be deleted (point to this comment)

Answer (score 3):

This solution/configuration solved my 400 and 502 errors

## nginx conf [ key point ]

```
upstream goaccess {
    server localhost:7890;
    keepalive 60;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl; 
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/fullchain.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/privkey.pem; 
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; 
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
    server_name rp.test.com;
    root  /var/www/goaccess;
    index  index.html;
    location / {
            try_files $uri  $uri/ @goaccess;
            alias /var/www/goaccess/;
            index  index.html;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_buffering on;            
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
            proxy_connect_timeout 600s;
            proxy_send_timeout 600s;
            proxy_read_timeout 600s;
            proxy_temp_path  /var/nginx/proxy_temp;
    }

    location @goaccess{
            proxy_pass http://goaccess;
    }

}
```

## goaccess [ goaccess.sh ]

```
#!/bin/sh
goaccess  /root/test2_nginx_log/www.test2.com_access.log -o /var/www/goaccess/index.html --real-time-html --origin=https://rp.test.com --addr=0.0.0.0 --port=7890 --ws-url=wss://rp.test.com --ssl-cert=/etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/fullchain.pem --ssl-key=/etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/privkey.pem  --time-format=%H:%M:%S --date-format=%d/%b/%Y --log-format=COMBINED
```

## sshfs [ run_sshfs.sh ]

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $(mount | grep 'root@111.111.111.xxx:/data/log/server/nginx' | wc -l) -ne 1 ]
then
    echo 'yourpassword' | sshfs root@111.111.111.xxx:/data/log/server/nginx /root/test2_nginx_log -o password_stdin,allow_other
else
    exit 0
fi
```

Finally this sh for check goaccess was running or not and the mount was online or not then restart that.

## check and restart [ cr.sh ]

```
#!/bin/bash
if pgrep -x "goaccess" > /dev/null 
then
    clear ;
    echo "goaccess is running!"
    sleep 1
    echo "now cutting down goaccess...please wait"
    sleep 2
    kill `pgrep goaccess`
    echo "cut down done"
    sleep 1
    echo "now check mount test2 nginx log folder..."
    cd /root/ && ./run_sshfs.sh
    sleep 2
    echo "mount done"
    sleep 1
    echo "now restart goaccess..."
    cd /root/ && sudo nohup ./goaccess.sh > goaccess.log 2>&1 &
    sleep 2
    echo "goaccess was restarting success!"
    sleep 1
    echo "now all done!"
    exit 1
else
    clear ;
    echo "goaccess is down!"
    sleep 1
    echo "now check mount test2 nginx log folder..."
    cd /root/ && ./run_sshfs.sh
    sleep 2
    echo "mount done"
    sleep 1
    echo "now start goaccess..."
    cd /root/ && sudo nohup ./goaccess.sh > goaccess.log 2>&1 &
    sleep 2
    echo "goaccess was starting success!"
    sleep 1
    echo "now all done!"
fi
```

That all. Now open your url which looks like my 'rp.test.com' you should see something similar below (if without any other special condition).

Running:

[image: goaccess running]

> Notice: This is [CROTEL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10482507/crotel)'s solution initially posted in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56946742/4), subsequently moved by community members to a community wiki answer to conform to Stack Overflow's Q/A format